# Subsetting then splitting gives empty list elements

Tags: r, split, subset

code:

```
c=rep(4,4)
f=data.frame("1"=c("a","b","c","d"),c)
s=subset(f,is.element(f[[1]], c("a","b")))
s3=split(s,s[1])
s3
```

output:

```
s3
$a
  X1 c
1  a 4

$b
  X1 c
2  b 4

$c
[1] X1 c 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$d
[1] X1 c 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How can I prevent or delete these empty elements for ($c,$d) without completely altering the code? Or alternately, can I lapply on this list skipping these bum values? thanks.

Comment: try using  na.rm=TRUE

Comment: Your data.frame X1 column is of type factor and not character, try creating the data.frame in this way : `f=data.frame("1"=c("a","b","c","d"),c,stringsAsFactors=F)`, or drop the unused factor levels after subsetting using: `s<-droplevels(s)`

Comment: Or `split(s,s[1], drop = TRUE)`